# UIAlertView setMessage do nothing

Tags: ios, progress-bar, uialertview

I'm trying to show upload progress in UIAlertView. I have an API with my server subclass of AFHTTPClient and some code where I send progress info to my view

```
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten,long long totalBytesWritten,long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
 {
     float progress = totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
     request *svc = [[request alloc] init];
     [svc setProgress:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress]];
     NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

 }];
```

When uploading process starts I create UIAlertView  in my View

API file

```
if (uploadFile) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:uploadFile name:@"file" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        request *svcAlert = [[request alloc] init];
        [svcAlert showProgressAlert];
    }
```

View file

```
- (void) showProgressAlert{
progressBarAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Идет загрузка"
                                                      message: @"0"
                                                     delegate: self
                                            cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];

progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle: UIProgressViewStyleBar];

progressView.frame = CGRectMake (20, 20, 50, 30);

[progressBarAlert addSubview:progressView];


[progressBarAlert show];
}
```

Then in my View I'm also trying to change UIAlertView message parameter with setMessage but nothing happens. ProgressView doesn't show up in AlertView even thought I'm adding it with addSubview.

```
-(void) setProgress: (NSNumber *) progress {
progressView.progress = [progress floatValue];
//progressBarAlert.message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", progress];
[progressBarAlert setMessage:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Загрузка %@", progress]];

}
```

And the last question, how do I close UIAlertView without pressing cancel button?

Also I've tried to add subView to my view instead of using alertView, but app crashed with uncaught exception. Maybe someone could give me any advice about this task.

Comment: Be aware that adding any subview to the `UIAlertView` is not longer supported in iOS 7.

Comment: thx, I will not use subView, but if setMessage will work it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

I will refer you to the Apple Documentation in regards to [`UIAlertView` Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) and specifically

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

What you are trying to do by doing `[progressBarAlert addSubview:progressView];` isn't allowed and will get your app rejected from the Apple review process. In iOS7 `addSubview:` never calls the super on `UIView` so doesn't actually do anything. So I wouldn't recommend doing this at all. There are however custom alert views like https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview that you can use to get what you are after.